# Mapkitの地図上に画像を表示したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

Objective-CでiOSアプリの開発を行っていてMapkitで表示されている地図上に画像を重ねたいのですがどうにも情報が出てきません。
この場合どのような方法が考えられるでしょうか？

Comment: [Map Kit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/)や、やや情報が古いと思いますが、[位置情報とマッププログラミングガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/LocationAwarenessPG.pdf)などの公式リファレンスは参照されましたでしょうか？

Comment: リファレンスにはマシン上で描画した多角形などをオーバーレイして表示するサンプルなどはあったのですが画像データを表示しているものや画像データをオーバーレイする方法が書いてなかったので
MKOverlayRendererが怪しいとは思ったんですが...

Comment: ピンの代わりに画像を使いたいというような簡単な用途であれば、`MKAnnotationView`が使えます。他にも`MKPolygonView`の`drawRect:`を改造して画像を表示するようにしたり、方法自体はいろいろあるはずですので、どういったことをやりたいかによる感じですねー。

Comment: アノテーションはあまり関係ないですね
やりたいことは地図上の一部の地域にオリジナルの地図をオーバーレイ、もしくは置き換えしたいってところなんですが

Comment: それでしたら、`MKOverlayRenderer`や`MKTileOverlayRenderer`ですね。高度なことをやろうとすると、空間参照系の知識が必要になるので、確かにあまり情報がない領域かもしれませんね…。実装としては古地図系アプリが参考になるかもしれません。（ただMapKitを使わず、Route-Meライブラリを使ってるものもあると思いますが）

Comment: MKOverlayRendererあたりをカスタムすればできそうな雰囲気はあるんですけども。ありがとうございました。他に何か有用な情報ありましたら回答に書いていただけるとありがたいです。